# How to change null values?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, null

> > The code works but returns
> >     the following error -
>
> TypeError: Error # 1009: Can not access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.at lost_fla ::MainTimeline / check ()
>   [lost_fla.MainTimeline :: frame1: 44]
>
> trace (smb_btn) = null
>
> trace (check) = function () {}
>
> trace (txt_inpt) = null
>
> What can be done to change the null values​​?

```
import fl.controls.Button
import fl.controls.TextInput
import flash.utils.Timer
import flash.events.MouseEvent

        smb_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, check);
    function check (e:MouseEvent):void{
        if (txt_inpt.text == "12345"){
            hotel++
            gotoAndPlay (952, "Cena 2");
            trace(smb_btn)
            trace(txt_inpt)
            }
            if (txt_inpt.text == "131313"){
            gotoAndPlay (735, "Cena 3");
            }
            if (txt_inpt.text == "t"){
            gotoAndPlay (693, "Cena 3");
            }
            if (txt_inpt.text == "141414"){
            gotoAndPlay (727, "Cena 4");
            }
        if (txt_inpt.text == "maze"){
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            gotoAndPlay (483,"Cena 7");
            }   
        if (txt_inpt.text == "54321"){
            gotoAndPlay (239,"Cena 4");
            }
        if (txt_inpt.text == "12123"){
            gotoAndPlay (358,"Cena 3");
            }
        if (txt_inpt.text == "191918"){
            stone++
            stone++
            stone++
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            gotoAndPlay (950,"Cena 8");
            }
        }
```

Comment: dropbox.com/s/jnn9sofj42tqey2/lost.fla  
    <- LINK --- File available for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should verify the names of the text field and button of yours, they should be named exactly like spelled in code, and the name should be assigned while designing the MC they are located at.

Comment: Checked! They are! To certify I copy and paste. Still the same error.

Comment: Okay, check the code context. It's possible those TF and button are located in a container MC, meaning you have to address them via that MC, like `container_mc.smb_btn`. Also, in general, a null error is just that, something isn't there, and **you** have to place it where you need it.

Comment: Peraphs you're managing ''state'' in your form and the visibility of these components, depends b y the state

Comment: @JoeTaras Shouldn't depend, visibility does not nullify variables. Most likely he's messing up with control and frames.

Comment: The code works fine but returns this error. The text field and the botton are working and showing wen testing. The desktop debuger have the option to dismiss this error and The function does what it made for. On the phone it dosent show any problem. But apple dosent accept that. So all i need to do is to change the null values I think.

Comment: @Vesper. Hi, state visibility impacts on graphical object. You have txt_inp. If this component is linked to state wieh includeIn statement this is NULL until state has changed. The code, as I've red, it's OK, it need the interation with user to understand eventualy an issue.

Comment: @Vesper dropbox.com/s/jnn9sofj42tqey2/lost.fla <--- file for download

Comment: According to your error, the object that is being found as "null" when the application is trying to act on it is on line 44. I'm only counting 40 lines here. Maybe check your code and see what line 44 looks like.

Comment: Thanks every one! apple has aprove the app whith the error. Running on a device the error dosen´t show up.

Answer (score 0):

Apple received the software with error and approve. Since the error does not cause even a problem, I believe that has not been taken seriously, but it still exists and I'm just ignoring the existence of it. I appreciate the help from everyone. Special tanks to Vesper.